# GA4 (google analytics 4): Is there any way to know how many users are on an application

Tags: google-analytics

Let's say we have two microservice (say angular) web applications with following home pages:

http://host.com/app1/landing-page

http://host.com/app2/landing-page

Google Analytics UA to GA4 transition seem to have taken 'the default ability to actively track users who on web=pages' away.

Given the above; if the requirement is to know if there are any users currently on an application (application1 or application2); is there any GA4 feature that is available out of the box to track active users on an application? If the answer is no; Is there any intelligent way to build it based on GA4 events and event properties that get propagated from a given application to GA4 analytics tool?